# Webplayer exit with error in webrouser

Tags: memory, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I make app on webplayer with Unity3d and run it in webbrowser. My application load big count of gameobjects with meshes in scene (with assetbundels). And in some moments it exit with error.
Some part of log:

```
 DynamicHeapAllocator allocation probe 1 failed - Could not get memory for     large allocation 2273563.
 DynamicHeapAllocator allocation probe 2 failed - Could not get memory for large  allocation 2273563.
 DynamicHeapAllocator allocation probe 1 failed - Could not get memory for large allocation 2273563.
DynamicHeapAllocator allocation probe 1 failed - Could not get memory for large allocation 2273563.
DynamicHeapAllocator allocation probe 2 failed - Could not get memory for large allocation 2273563.
DynamicHeapAllocator allocation probe 3 failed - Could not get memory for large allocation 2273563.
DynamicHeapAllocator allocation probe 4 failed - Could not get memory for large allocation 2273563.
DynamicHeapAllocator out of memory - Could not get memory for large allocation 2273563!
Could not allocate memory: System out of memory!
Trying to allocate: 2273563B with 16 alignment. MemoryLabel: TempOverflow
Allocation happend at: Line:133 in    C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Allocator/ThreadsafeLinearAllocator.cpp
Memory overview

[ ALLOC_DEFAULT ] used: 442692589B | peak: 0B | reserved: 487509325B 
[ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 4194304B 
[ ALLOC_GFX ] used: 170789102B | peak: 0B | reserved: 210481854B 
[ ALLOC_CACHEOBJECTS ] used: 340080196B | peak: 0B | reserved: 352321536B 
[ ALLOC_TYPETREE ] used: 731568B | peak: 0B | reserved: 5242880B 
[ ALLOC_PROFILER ] used: 2986680B | peak: 0B | reserved: 12582912B 
Could not allocate memory: System out of memory!
Trying to allocate: 2273563B with 16 alignment. MemoryLabel: TempOverflow
Allocation happend at: Line:133 in       C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Allocator/ThreadsafeLinearAllocator.cpp
Memory overview

[ ALLOC_DEFAULT ] used: 442692589B | peak: 0B | reserved: 487509325B 
[ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 4194304B 
[ ALLOC_GFX ] used: 170789102B | peak: 0B | reserved: 210481854B 
[ ALLOC_CACHEOBJECTS ] used: 340080196B | peak: 0B | reserved: 352321536B 
[ ALLOC_TYPETREE ] used: 731568B | peak: 0B | reserved: 5242880B 
[ ALLOC_PROFILER ] used: 2986680B | peak: 0B | reserved: 12582912B 


(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Allocator/MemoryManager.cpp Line: 980)

Exit with error code: 2

========== OUTPUTING STACK TRACE ==================



========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========

Could not allocate memory: System out of memory!
Trying to allocate: 2273536B with 16 alignment. MemoryLabel: TempJobAlloc
Allocation happend at: Line:379 in    C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Utilities/dynamic_array.h
```

I print in screen: Profiler.GetTotalAllocatedMemory(), Profiler.GetTotalReservedMemory(), Profiler.GetTotalAllocatedMemory(), unusedReservedMemory = Profiler.GetTotalUnusedReservedMemory(), unusedReservedMemory not null when application exit with error. Screenshot when application not responding http://prntscr.com/adf9of.

Comment: why wouldn't you use webGL?

Comment: We are not else use WebGL, because technical problems exists.

Comment: Webplayer is no longer updated and will be removed from unity in 5.4 which is next week. WebGL is your only option and you had over 1 year to switch to it.

Comment: Do you think, that its errors not apear in WebGL?

Comment: The the only to find out is to build your game for webgl. Click and click and you are done then you can see if it works or not. Webplayer may be throwing those errors because it is outdated.